# find Absolute path of "Desktop" location using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

How I get Absolute path of "Desktop" location using PHP?

Comment: PHP is executed on the server ; there is quite no *Desktop* there -- or you should add more informations about the context of your question ;-)

Comment: Desktop folder on the server-side or the client-side?

Comment: By the way: keep in mind that the "desktop folder" may not exists, in Linux the "desktop folder" is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

In php? By no means, as php is serverside. You'll have to use javascript, but I don't think you are allowed to access the file system with javascript, so no dice there either.

Comment: Yup, you're not allowed to browse the client's filesystem in JavaScript, so you can't find the full path of the Desktop folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH");
```

Answer (score 0):

$desktop will be destination to save files ,And to be sure from result try make scandir to show files in desktop folder

```
$userfolders =  getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH") ; 
 
$desktop = $userfolders .'/desktop';

// Sort in ascending order - this is default
$files = scandir($desktop);
print_r($files);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps

Comment: $desktop will be destination to save files , to be sure from result i make scandir to show files in desktop folder

Comment: Please edit your answer and include the explanation there.